# Debugging ASP.NET - Can I copy XML comments to the debug folder?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, xml-comments

I have an ASP.NET project which generates an XML documentation file. I'm using [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) and would like it to be able to reference the XML comments file while debugging.

However, when I run the project in debug mode, the only files that get copied to the temporary folder are the DLL, PDB, and __AssemblyInfo__.ini.

Is there any way to cause the XML documents to be copied to the temporary folder, or any way to reference files contained in the project's BIN folder that I can access in a uniform way at both debug and publish time?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the xml documents to the debug folder, by changing the output path of the entire project.

You have to:

1. Right click on your project in solution explorer and click properties
2. Go to Build
3. Change to output path for this project and select the output folder of your main project

Change the xml file output path:

[image]